# ¿Como mostrar y actualizar datos sin recargar pagina usando ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hola llevo atorado un buen rato con esto y no encuentro una solución. Estoy haciendo una consulta en php para ello utilizo lo siguiente

```
$html = "";
foreach ($result as $data) {
    $names = $data['nombres'];
    $html .= "<div class='div-container'>
                    <p>$names</p>
            </div>";
}
echo $html;
```

Con foreach recorro mis datos y los consulto con ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: index.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    $(".container-father").html(result);
                },
            });
        });
```

Finalmente los muestro en html

```
 <div class="container-father" id="reload-div">
 </div>
```

El caso es que los datos se muestran pero no encuentro la manera de que los nuevos datos ingresados se muestren automáticamente sin recargar la pagina o si actualizo algun dato igual se muestren sin recargar la pagina probe con load jquery sobre todo
 `$("#reload-div").load(" #reload-div");`
pero no consigo nada. Cabe mencionar no uso ningun evento por lo que no entiendo bien como se haria para actualizar la pagina automaticamente.

Comment: Con la función `load` es la forma más fácil, tu no has puesto la URL : `$("#reload-div").load(AQUI_VA_LA_URL)`

Comment: En el código que has puesto el ajax lo realizas en evento ``ready`` que se ejecuta cuando carga la página. Luego si quieres que algo se actualice tienes que tener ya sean un button, link o cualquier etiqueta asociado a un evento de tal forma que este vuelva a ejecutable ajax. Adi como lo tienes el ajax solo se ejecuta cuando cargas o refrescas la página. Ahora también puedes tener un timer que cada cierto tiempo ejecute el ajax$. En resumen luego de la carga en algun lugar debes tener algo que vuelva a ejecutar el ajax.

Comment: Por ejemplo, un evento click de un button puede invocar a una función javasxript que hace la llamada al ajaxnybsebactualicenla página sin necesidad denunbsubmit

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich entiendo que agregando un timer seria la unica manera de conseguir lo que requiero. Gracias

Comment: @Yussef si habia colocado asi como mencionas pero me da error 404. Y si no me da error 404 pues tampoco veo ningun cambio